# Convert stored procedure to function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I need to make use of a function to be able to consume it through Power BI due to the Direct Query data connectivity mode, there is no way that Power BI can make use of stored procedures.

Therefore I am trying to create a function from a stored procedure.

The following is the stored procedure from which I want to create the function:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SPTest]   
    @Anio int,
    @Mes int
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @AnioMes  varchar(8),
            @AnioMes6 varchar(8)

    IF @Anio IS NULL
        SELECT @Anio = YEAR(GETDATE()),
               @Mes  = MONTH(GETDATE())

    SELECT 
        @AnioMes = (CASE WHEN @Mes = 12 THEN @Anio + 1 ELSE @Anio END * 100 + 
                    CASE WHEN @Mes = 12 THEN 1 ELSE @Mes + 1 END) * 100 + 1
    SELECT
        @AnioMes6 = CONVERT(varchar(8), DATEADD(mm, -5, @AnioMes), 112)

    SELECT 
        YEAR(DATEADD(second, DATEDIFF(second, GETUTCDATE(), GETDATE()), CREATEDDATETIME)) * 100 + 
        MONTH(DATEADD(second, DATEDIFF(second, GETUTCDATE(), GETDATE()), CREATEDDATETIME)) AS AnioMes,
        DATEADD(second, DATEDIFF(second, GETUTCDATE(), GETDATE()), CREATEDDATETIME) AS FECHA_CREACION,
        INPUTSUBJECT,
        CASE 
            WHEN TOWTYPE = 1 THEN 'T1'
            WHEN TOWTYPE = 2 THEN 'T2'
            WHEN TOWTYPE = 3 THEN 'T3'
            WHEN TOWTYPE = 4 THEN 'T4'
            ELSE ''
        END AS TOWTYPE,
        [VENDNAME]
    FROM 
        TRUCKS
    WHERE
        YEAR(DATEADD(second, DATEDIFF(second, GETUTCDATE(), GETDATE()), CREATEDDATETIME)) >= yEAR(@AnioMes6)
        AND MONTH(DATEADD(second, DATEDIFF(second, GETUTCDATE(), GETDATE()), CREATEDDATETIME)) <= MONTH(@AnioMes)
        AND DATEADD(second, DATEDIFF(second, GETUTCDATE(), GETDATE()), CREATEDDATETIME) >= '20160701'
```

Hope someone can give me some guidance on how to create a function from this stored procedure

I have tried to do the following:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SPTest]
(
    @Anio   int,
    @Mes    int,
    @AnioMes    varchar(8),
    @AnioMes6   varchar(8)
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
BEGIN

        if @Anio is null
        Select  @Anio   = YEAR(GETDATE()),
                @Mes    = MONTH(GETDATE())

    Select  @AnioMes    = (case when @Mes=12 then @Anio+1 else @Anio end *100 + Case when @Mes=12 then 1 else @Mes+1 end)*100 + 1
    Select  @AnioMes6   = convert(varchar(8), DATEADD(mm, -5, @AnioMes), 112 )


    SELECT year(DATEADD(second, DATEDIFF(second, GETUTCDATE(), GETDATE()), CREATEDDATETIME))*100+month(DATEADD(second, DATEDIFF(second, GETUTCDATE(), GETDATE()), CREATEDDATETIME)) as AnioMes
          ,DATEADD(second, DATEDIFF(second, GETUTCDATE(), GETDATE()), CREATEDDATETIME) as FECHA_CREACION
          ,INPUTSUBJECT
          ,Case When TOWTYPE = 1 then 'T1'
                When TOWTYPE = 2 then 'T2'
                When TOWTYPE = 3 then 'T3'
                When TOWTYPE = 4 then 'T4'
                Else ''
            End as TOWTYPE
          ,[VENDNAME]
        FROM TRUCKS
        Where   year(DATEADD(second, DATEDIFF(second, GETUTCDATE(), GETDATE()), CREATEDDATETIME)) >= yEAR(@AnioMes6)
        and month(DATEADD(second, DATEDIFF(second, GETUTCDATE(), GETDATE()), CREATEDDATETIME)) <= MONTH(@AnioMes)
        AND     DATEADD(second, DATEDIFF(second, GETUTCDATE(), GETDATE()), CREATEDDATETIME) >= '20160701'

    END 

    RETURN
```

I get the following error in the BEGIN:

> Incorrect syntax near BEGIN

Comment: @DaleK 
I have already tried to do it based on the documentation, you can check in my last update

Comment: @DaleK But in my case I can't ignore the parameters, I also use it in the stored procedure, any corrections that I should make to the function?

Comment: Have a read through the [CREATE FUNCTION (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-function-transact-sql) documentation. If you want a multi-statement table-valued function like you present then you need to specify the schema of the table you're returning.

Comment: @DaleK You mean these variables `@Anio
    @Month
    @YearMonth
    @ AnioMes6`

Comment: @DaleK I need to make use of a function to be able to consume it through Power BI due to the Direct Query data connectivity mode, there is no way that Power BI can make use of stored procedures, that is why I am forced to make use of a function

Comment: @user11804298 did the answer provided help you?

Comment: @DaleK You created an answer but then you deleted it, possibly it would have helped me validate

Comment: @user11804298 Charlieface's answer is far better than mine, hence why I deleted it. Did you try using that answer?

Comment: @DaleK It is indeed a very good option, I already vote positively for your answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, you should *always* try to stick to **inline** Table Valued Functions, as they perform far better.

An inline function has no `BEGIN` or `END` and can only contain a single `AS RETURN SELECT` statement.

- Note how the variables have been converted into `VALUES` clauses
- Avoid using functions against columns. Instead of converting `CREATEDDATETIME` to a time zone to compare, convert your parameters to UTC
- For the same reason, don't compare parts of a date, construct the start and end points and compare against that
- Don't use string conversions to create dates, it's slow and can be non-deterministic. Instead use the proper date functions available

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[SPTest] (
    @month DATETIME
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS RETURN

SELECT
   v1.AnioMes
  ,t.CREATEDDATETIME AT TIME ZONE 'YourTimeZoneHere' as FECHA_CREACION
  ,t.INPUTSUBJECT
  ,CASE WHEN t.TOWTYPE IN (1,2,3,4)
        THEN CONCAT('T', t.TOWTYPE)
        ELSE '' END AS TOWTYPE
  ,t.[VENDNAME]

FROM (VALUES (
    DATEADD(day, 1, EOMONTH(TODATETIMEOFFSET(@month, 0)))
)) v1(AnioMes)

CROSS APPLY (VALUES (
    DATEADD(month, -5, v1.AnioMes)
)) v2(AnioMes6)

CROSS JOIN TRUCKS t

WHERE t.CREATEDDATETIME >= v2.AnioMes6
  AND t.CREATEDDATETIME <  v1.AnioMes
  AND t.CREATEDDATETIME >= '20160701';
```