# Error creating function with temporary tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, t-sql, temporal-tables

I am creating a function that contains a temporary table, it is a bit difficult for me to use the function with a temporary table, I totally do not know if it is allowed within a function since I am new to the new one.

The function I am trying to create is the following:

```
CREATE FUNCTION FunctionTest (
    @Anio   int=null,
    @Mes    int=Null,
    @Meses  int=6

)
RETURNS @Tabla TABLE (
    AnioMes INT,
    Viaje VARCHAR(30),
    IdPorte INT,
    Carga VARCHAR(20),
    Peso numeric(32, 16)
)
AS
BEGIN

    Declare @AnioMes    varchar(8),
            @AnioMes6   varchar(8)

    if @Anio is null
        Select  @Anio   = YEAR(GETDATE()),
                @Mes    = MONTH(GETDATE())

    Select  @AnioMes    = (case when @Mes=12 then @Anio+1 else @Anio end *100 + Case when @Mes=12 then 1 else @Mes+1 end)*100 + 1
    Select  @AnioMes6   = convert(varchar(8), DATEADD(mm, -@Meses, @AnioMes), 112 )

    INSERT INTO @Tabla (AnioMes,Viaje,IdPorte,Carga,Peso)   
    SELECT  year(cpsj.Delivery)*100 + MONTH(cpsj.Delivery) as AnioMes,  
            tr.TId as Viaje,
            cpsj.PId as IdPorte,            
            CASE WHEN tr.Load = 1 THEN 'CARGADO'
                WHEN tr.Load = 2 THEN 'VACIO'
            END  as Carga, 
            cpsj.Weight as Peso,            
    into #Temp
    FROM BDNEW.dbo.CENPACKSTOREJOIN cpsj 
    inner join TRANS tr on cpsj.ipId = tr.ipId
    inner join OPERA oper on tr.OId = oper.OId  
    WHERE   cpsj.Id = 'ID001'
    AND     tr.Area = 'lost'
    AND     tr.Status       = 2
    GROUP BY cpsj.Delivery, cpsj.IName
    ORDER BY cpsj.ipId

    if @AnioMes6 < '20160101'
        insert #Temp
        SELECT  Year(cpsj.Delivery)*100 + MONTH(cpsj.Delivery) as AnioMes,  
                tr.TId as Viaje,
                cpsj.PId as IdPorte,        
                CASE WHEN tr.Load = 1 THEN 'CARGADO'
                    WHEN tr.Load = 2 THEN 'VACIO'
                END  as Carga, 
                cpsj.Weight as Peso,                
        FROM BDOLD.dbo.CENPACKSTOREJOIN cpsj 
        inner join TRANS tr on cpsj.ipId = tr.ipId
        inner join OPERA oper on tr.OId = oper.OId
        WHERE   cpsj.Id = 'ID001'
        AND     tr.Area = 'lost'    
        AND     tr.Status       = 2
        GROUP BY cpsj.Delivery, cpsj.IName 
        ORDER BY cpsj.ipId

    Delete  #Temp
    where   viaje in (
                    select MAX(Viaje)
                    from    #Temp
                    group by IdPorte
                    having COUNT(IdPorte) > 1
                    )

    
    Select  AnioMes,
            Viaje,
            IdPorte, 
            Carga, 
            Peso, 
    from #Temp
    GROUP BY AnioMes,IdPorte Viaje, Carga, Peso
    ORDER BY AnioMes,IdPorte

RETURN 

END
```

If you notice I am making use of a temporary table called `#Temp`.

As an error message when trying to compile the function I get the following error message:

> Cannot access temporary tables from within a function.

That is why I mentioned earlier if you can really make use of temporary tables in a function.

I appreciate anyone who can give me guidance on how to handle this function.

Comment: I am trying to wrap my head around `INSERT INTO @Tabla ... SELECT ... INTO #Temp` ... please explain why you think you need both `@Tabla` and `#Temp` here?

Comment: The `INSERT INTO @Tabla` is something that I was creating for my function, I don't really know if it should be used there or if I should make some modification in the syntax

Comment: You should just `INSERT INTO @Tabla`, then update/delete `@Tabla`, then the contents of `@Tabla` after your modifications are what will be returned by the function.

Comment: @AaronBertrand You can please add a new answer based on your comment but taking into account the syntax that I post in my question

Comment: @AaronBertrand You know how it is when [you spend loads of time answering a question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69730679/14868997) and OP just posts another question showing they completely ignored your advice...... Pretty hurtful, TBH

Comment: @Charlieface LOL that's _never_ happened to me...

Answer (score 0):

You either use

```
INSERT INTO @Tabla (AnioMes,Viaje,IdPorte,Carga,Peso)   
SELECT  year(cpsj.Delivery)*100 ...
```

Or

```
SELECT  year(cpsj.Delivery)*100 ...
INTO #Temp
FROM...
```

**Not** both:

```
INSERT INTO @Tabla (AnioMes,Viaje,IdPorte,Carga,Peso)  
SELECT  year(cpsj.Delivery)*100 ...
INTO #Temp
FROM...
```

And also you can't use temp tables in functions.

Comment: If I don't use INSERT INTO @Table I get the error message `Invalid use of a side-effecting operator 'SELECT' within a function`

Comment: Its because you can't just select result set without assigning it to a variable. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13603111/sql-function-error-invalid-use-of-side-effecting-operator-select-within-a-fun